# Can LoadRunner Receive Data By UDP Packets?

Tags: c, sockets, load, performance-testing, loadrunner

We want to receive packets from udp sockets, the udp packets have variable length and we don't know how long they really are until we receive them (parts of them exactly, length were written in the sixth byte).

We tried the function **lrs_set_receive_option with MarkerEnd** only to find it has no help on this issue. The reason why we want to receive by packets is that we need to respond some packet by sending back user-defined udp packets.

Is there anybody knows how achieve that?

**UPDATE**

1. The LR version seems to be v10 or v11.
2. We need respond an incoming udp packet by sending back a udp packet immediately.
   The udp packet may be like this

   ---

   | orc code | packet length |   Real DATA |

   ---
3. Issue is we can't let loadrunner return data for each packets,  sometimes it returns many packets in a buffer, sometimes it waits until timeout though when there has been an incoming packet in the socket buffer. **While in the c programming language world, when calling recvfrom(udp socket) we are returned only one udp packet per time (per call) which is want we really want.**

Comment: Could you add LR version and the protocol you use please

Comment: @Buzzy don't remember clearly.. it may be v10 or v11.

Answer (score 1):

If you need raw socket support to intercept at the packet level then you are likely going to have to jump to a DLL virtual user in Visual Studio with the raw socket support.

As to your question on UDP support: Yes, a Winsock user supports both core transport types, UDP and TCP.  TCP being the more common variant as connection oriented.   However, packet examination is at layer 3 of the OSI model for the carrier protocol IP.   The ACK should come before you receive the dataflow for your use in the script.  You are looking at assembled data flows in the data.ws when you jump to the TCP and UDP level.

Now, you are likely receiving a warning on receive buffer size mismatch which is taking you down this path with a mismatch to the recording size.  There is an easy way to address this.  If you take your send buffer and construct it using the **lrs_set_send_buffer()** function, then anything that returns will be taken as correct, ignoring the previously recorded buffer size and not having to wait for a match or timeout before continuing.

Comment: Does it guarantee that we will receive udp packets one by one when using lrs_set_send_buffer function? We are worried that lrs_receive returns more than one incoming udp packets into the buffer, and we don't know this. Even more worse it will wait until timeout or content/size match though there are incoming packets.

Comment: All packets arrive one at a time.  That is the nature of packets.  Packets are sequences.  Packets can arrive out of sequence, hence the sequence number. http://www.scs.stanford.edu/09au-cs144/notes/l2-print.pdf  If you set your send buffer using lrs_set_send_buffer() then it WILL NOT WAIT for a match before continuing but it will wait for the end of transmission.

Comment: yes, I know all packets arrive one by one. For example there are 10 packets in the incoming socket buffer, we find LoadRunner put these 10 packets into one big buffer and return to use, while in the c language world we call recvfrom(socket) and we are returned only one udp packet per time.

Comment: regarding the lrs_set_send_buffer, we tried this function only to find that this doesn't solve our problem. it still can't return one udp packet per time, more worse that it will wait until time out whenever the buffer we provide doesn't match the data in incoming socket buffer, it may still return many udp packets into one in order to match the buffer we provide.

Comment: You are operating at the UDP interface and should not expect control to the packet level.  If you want that level of control then you will need to write your own DLL and operate directly the IP level in a raw sockets mode. (see above)